# can javafx print to dot matrix printer?

Tags: java, grails, printing, javafx

I have clients who still using dot matrix for making copies of printed documents (like invoice, reports, etc). I did a development using grails (web application) for internal company only (so it doesnt matter to install / update all java re in all computers)

I am still learning (just started) Javafx. can i use this javafx to print from file to dotmatrix printer ? or shall i use applet instead ? *friends of mine told me that java has lib to print to dot matrix, that's why i am stick to javafx or applet*

which one is the easier and better (also faster) using applet or javafx? the interface is quite simple, just a form with 2 input fields and a button for printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any Java API/Library can be accessed from JavaFX - there is no limitation. You can do the UI of the application and core logic in JavaFX and use the existing Java Lib for printing stuff (the [Print Service API](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/jps/index.html) might be a good start).

Doing this as an Applet might not be best idea, I would recommend using WebStart deployment.

Comment: is javafx needs kind of security something ? because i know that applet needed that.

Answer (score 2):

Java has a [Print Service API](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/jps/index.html). It would be worth checking that out.

I suspect it won't work via an applet, however (I would guess the security model gets in the way).

Comment: Your link is broken, please consider updating it!

Answer (score 0):

Applets can be signed so they can print as well. In addition, Applets using the new plugin have access to the JNLP apis, which includes a secure way of doing printing for unsigned apps.